# Passport JS Google OAuth2 - force login or account chooser

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-signin, passport.js

I have google login in my service written in nodejs+express and use passport-google-oauth to log in with google. 
On my site, I have a 'Sign in with Google' button. What I want, is to always show google login or Account Chooser when user hits this button. Instead, if I am logged in at exactly one google account in my browser, I immediately get logged in to service with this account. I've tried something like this when defining GoogleStrategy:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: REDIRECT_URL,
        passReqToCallback : true,
        prompt: 'select_account' // <--!!!
    }, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       //callback stuff
   })

})
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that prompt parameter was in wrong place. Instead placing it as argument of GoogleStrategy constructor, I should have put it into args of passport.authenticate() middleware

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: SCOPES,
    prompt: 'select_account'
}))
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me either, there must be more to this issue